# angular - Submit form by controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to submit form with controller function.  so i have following code :-

```
<form ng-submit="uploadLogo()" name="logoForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="file" name="letterhead" id="letterhead" required />    

<div>                                                
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-info">Upload</button>
</div>

</form>
```

Controller

```
$scope.uploadLogo = function () {
        Practices.updateLogo().save(function (res) {
            console.log('res :' + res);
        });

    }
```

Service

```
updateLogo: function () {
              return $resource('/api/practicesUpload',
                  {}, { 'save': { method: 'POST'} });
          }
```

routes

```
 app.post('/api/practicesUpload', multipartMiddleware, practices.uploadLogo);
```

Server Side

```
exports.uploadLogo = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Called');
    console.log(req.files);
    var tempfile = req.files.letterhead.path;
    ....
}
```

The Server Side gets called but i don't get files. I get error that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined` doesn't exist.

If i directly submit form, everything works well :-

```
<form action="/api/practicesUpload" name="logoForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How to submit form by controller. The reason for me to submit it by controller is to show a `Success Message` by creating a flag in controller.

Comment: what does Practices.updateLogo().query() do?

Comment: It will call the service...will go to `routes`.

Comment: but isn't .query a GET method???

Comment: Correct me wt to do....i am completely new to angular...so i have less idea of how code works.

Comment: Well you did not provide the rest of your code so it's difficult. Is Practices a service using the $resource approach? If yes, check this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource, using "query" is a GET request. Try "save". Another option is to use $http.post

Comment: yes it is using $resource..see edited question.